# Can't understand why php is giving me this error

Tags: php

my php script is givimg me this error, don't know what what's happening :
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/u381071273/public_html/upload/myfiles.php on line 8` , the follwoing is code that im using to view loggedin user's contents

php code

```
<?php
include('models/db-settings.php');
include('models/config.php');
include('models/header.php');
$uplfolder = $_REQUEST['folder']; //The folder required by the user.
?>
<?php if(isUserLoggedIn()) { 
<div id='main' role='main'>
                <div id='blocks'>
            <ul class='grid'>
<?php
include 'models/viewdir.php'; //This script opens the user's folders.
?>
            </ul></div>
        </div>
    </body>
}
else
{

}
?>
```

Comment: `<div id='main' role='main'>` and what follows is not valid PHP code. You'll either need to break out of PHP context (...`?>`) or use `echo` statements to output that HTML markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include('models/db-settings.php');
include('models/config.php');
include('models/header.php');
$uplfolder = $_REQUEST['folder']; //The folder required by the user.
?>
<?php if(isUserLoggedIn()) { ?>
<div id='main' role='main'>
            <div id='blocks'>
        <ul class='grid'>
<?php
include 'models/viewdir.php'; //This script opens the user's folders.
?>
        </ul></div>
    </div>
</body>

//next error will be here
<?php
}
else
{

}
?>
```

Comment: @Arshsingh here comes the twist which answer you will accept ? :P

Comment: hahaha ya man 2 answers which solved my prob

Answer (score 3):

change line 8 to

```
<?php if(isUserLoggedIn()) {  ?>
```

You were not closing PHP before starting HTML output

And for line 21:

```
    </body>
<?php }
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/u381071273/public_html/upload/myfiles.php on line 22 now this is the error

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with the code is that you haven't properly escaped the html part from php

Your Code:

```
<?php
include('models/db-settings.php');
include('models/config.php');
include('models/header.php');
$uplfolder = $_REQUEST['folder']; //The folder required by the user.
?>
<?php if(isUserLoggedIn()) { 
<div id='main' role='main'>
                <div id='blocks'>
            <ul class='grid'>
<?php
include 'models/viewdir.php'; //This script opens the user's folders.
?>
            </ul></div>
        </div>
    </body>
}
else
{

}
?>
```

Change it to this :

```
<?php
include('models/db-settings.php');
include('models/config.php');
include('models/header.php');
$uplfolder = $_REQUEST['folder']; //The folder required by the user.
?>
<?php if(isUserLoggedIn()) { ?>
<div id='main' role='main'>
                <div id='blocks'>
            <ul class='grid'>
<?php
include 'models/viewdir.php'; //This script opens the user's folders.
?>
            </ul></div>
        </div>
    </body>
<?php
}
else
{

}
?>
```